# Classifying Group Generated by two cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider a group of order 3 that is cyclic and a group of order 2 that is cyclic. How does one fully show this is isomorphic to $Z_3 \times Z_2\,$?

That is,

$$ |\langle a\rangle| = 3 \ \text{ and }  |\langle b\rangle| = 2 
\\
\implies \langle a,b\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_2}.$$

The example I have is the group of real valued functions equipped with the operation composition

$$ A(x)=(1-x)^{-1},
\\ C(x) = x^{-1}.$$

Clearly $A$ has order three and $C$ has order two.

My thoughts:
$$ C^{-1}\langle A\rangle C= C\langle A\rangle C.$$
One can show that $$\;\;C(A(C(x))) = A^{2} \ \in \ \langle A\rangle.$$

Hence $\langle A\rangle$ is a normal group in $G$ defined as the group generated by $A$ and $C$. Therefore we can define an internal semidirect product for $\langle A\rangle \rtimes \langle C\rangle $ that is isomorphic to the group generated by $A,C$.

However, how does one then go further and convert this semidirect product to a direct product of Z mod 2 and Z mod 3 ?

Comment: You are mistaken that $C$ normalizes the cyclic group generated by $A$. The group that you have is actually infinite.

Comment: $$ C(A(C(x))) = C(A(x^{-1})) = C(1-\frac{1}{x})^{-1}= 1-\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: $$A^{2}(x) = A(A(x)) = A((1-x)^{-1}) = (1-\frac{1}{1-x})^-{-1} = ( \frac{1-x-1}{1-x})^{-1} = ( \frac{x}{x-1})^{-1} = \frac{x-1}{x} = 1- \frac{1}{x} = A^{2} $$

Comment: If anything is wrong with that, I will be deeply sad as I have went based on this assumption for the last two hours grinding this question. Any insight would be VERY helpful

Comment: Oh, sorry, I confused your group with the more famous one, where the first generator is $z\mapsto -z^{-1}$ (the famous group is called the "modular group"). Your group is indeed the semidirect product $Z_2\ltimes Z_3$. It is **not** isomorphic to the direct product.

Comment: But the symmetric group $S_3$ has order 6 and is generated a pair of elements of orders 2 and 3, and it's not cyclic. Similarly the dihedral groups are generated by a pair of elements but they aren't cyclic (one element of order 2 and one of order $n$ for the symmetry group of the regular n-gon).

Comment: I just am struggling to understand what exactly is the semidirect product of Z mod 2 and Z mod 3 vs the direct product of Z mod 2 and Z mod 3. What exactly makes S3 isomorphic to one but not the other. This is a topic in group theory I have always struggled with